# Limit initial Doctrine QueryBuilder Response, Allow for "Load More"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, zend-framework, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine's query builder to get table of data and leveraging Zend to display the information on the page.  I'm using some Ajax to enable a "load more" function but I need to limit the initial number of rows returned while still being able to "load more" using the Ajax call that leverages the same repository function getAllNotifications.

Can this be accomplished in the action method within the Zend controller?  If not, what is the best way to do so?

Action method in the controller:

```
public function historyAction()
{
    $this->view->pageTitle = "Notification Center";

    $this->view->notifications = \Home\EntityUtils::getRepository('Notification')->getAllNotifications();
}
```

Load More action method in the controller:

```
public function loadMoreNotificationsAction()
{
    $offset = $this->getParam('offset');
    $limit = $this->getParam('limit', 30);

    //get notifications
    $this->view->notifications = \Home\EntityUtils::getRepository('Notification')->getAllNotifications($offset, $limit);

    //render notifications using partialLoop
    $notificationsHtml = $this->view->partialLoop("notificationHistoryRow.phtml", $this->view->notifications);

    //return notification html via json
    $this->_helper->json($notificationsHtml);
}
```

getAllNotifications method in the repository, used above:

```
public function getAllNotifications($offset = null, $limit = null)
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('n.date_posted, nt.name as type, nt.class, n.id, n.title, n.message, n.recipient_params')
        ->from('\Home\Entity\Notification', 'n')
        ->orderBy('n.date_posted', 'DESC')
        ->leftJoin('n.notification_type', 'nt');

    if ($limit) {
        $qb->setMaxResults($limit);
    }

    if ($offset) {
        $qb->setFirstResult($offset);
    }

    $results = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

    return $results;

}
```

JavaScript used for the "load more" functionality:

```
$(function() {
var offset = 0;

$("#load-more").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("load-more-notifications", {offset: offset, limit: 30}, function(response) {
        $(".notification-table-body").append(response);
        offset += 30;
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By utilizing the existing parameters for the `getAllNotifications(null, 30)` repository method I was able to set a limit for the initial page load without interfering with the load more function.

```
public function historyAction()
{
    $this->view->pageTitle = "Notification Center";
    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile("/js/tableSorter/jquery.tablesorter.min.js");

    $this->view->notifications = \Fisdap\EntityUtils::getRepository('Notification')->getAllNotifications(null, 30);
}
```